# How do I get element type="email" using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am currently trying to learn Cypress for Automation testing.

I want to find and click on this element:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control text-ellipsis-global GKMU5SYDM3B" id="gwt-uid-1419" data-empty="true">
```

I can't use the id, or that 'GKMU5SYDM3B' because these are both randomly generated by GWT.

I expect my command to resemble this:

```
cy.get('input').type('email').click().type('fake@email.com')
  .should('have.value', 'fake@email.com')
```

I tried this one and got the following error message:

```
CypressError: cy.type() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 4 elements.
```

Comment: I put a answer down below. but I have some questions. Why are you testing you can type into a input box? Perhaps you have a good reason, but you did not write that implementation. Also do you have access to the code? If so you might want to add your own date-test-id attribute on there to make it unique, if someone else adds another input of type email (say to verify the email), that will cause some problem.

Comment: Are there other inputs on your page that have a type of email? Is there some parent element such as a div or form that has an id or class? If so you could choose the parent then find the child to try to make it more unique.

Comment: @Maccurt I have been evaluating a number of methods of Automation testing, including Selenium, Nightwatch & this one, Cypress. In each case, I write a simple test to log in & out of our Web Client system. I am not responsible for any of the code, just the tests, so I have to adapt to whatever is there.

Comment: ahh, yes I know the role. We use Telerik (which I am trying to reduce). I have also used protractor.. From my experience using a lot of tools, I find Cypress my favorite so far. Protractor would probably be next. My goal is to get my developers to join more in this effort, they would use Cypress. I wish you luck in it. You will get some grief about it not working in Internet Explorer, but I think those are edge cases. For me Cypress makes it easy to test, the ability to MOCK the API calls is a game changer. I wish you luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
 cy.get("[type='email']")

 cy.get("[type='email']").type('myemail@domain.com')
```

What I always do, is try it in JQUERY first in the browser console. You should not have to click it to type into it.

if you have some parent element around, like a div you might also want to include that.

```
<div id='parent'>
    <input type="email" class="form-control text-ellipsis-global GKMU5SYDM3B" id="gwt-uid-1419" data-empty="true">
</div>
```

so you would then go

```
cy.get('#parent').find("[type='email']").type('myemail@domain.com')
```

Comment: My concern is you have other inputs on the page that are of type email also. If so show us more of your html structure, like the parent element and we can make it more unique.

Comment: I am having to click to type into element because GWT uses these placeholders. Makes life difficult. Can't even use Inspect in Firefox, as clicking on the placeholder changes it to a different element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to verify the typed 'email' in email's field.

First , type 'email' by using this type of locator.

```
cy.get("[type='email']").type('fake@email.com');
```

After type in 'email' field you can verify it by this assertion.

```
cy.get("[type='email']").should('have.value', 'fake@email.com')
```